# java invalidKeyException

Tags: java, encryption

Hi all i get this error when i am trying to copy and paste a ssh2 public key that i have generated.

here is the full stack trace of the error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:188)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:304)
    at com.josh.crypto.CryptoUtil.convertKeytoKeyObject(CryptoUtil.java:114)
    at com.josh.crypto.CryptoUtil.encryptData(CryptoUtil.java:80)
    at com.josh.ui.EncryptionView$2.actionPerformed(EncryptionView.java:112)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:370)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:386)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:66)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:281)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:184)
    ... 40 more
```

Here is the public key plain text i am using to convert to a byte array

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20130520"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAsE8aR2CIWuQgkeOsPhHDuGo+Rokr2cT+KS5L
sJFbEkB0R3XYXnOT3DU0CFrmHUX1PpcfTOSdxCIfeSXFHCGGWEXm4qx7ptNpm4vP
Scuzmlr/fjuQdb7lBQ0+OEP2LKuRHxt5oEVZvq/EvwENS5T2BiVUSvTwXUS6SKCh
ERydjXE=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

And here is the code that converts to byte array and uses x509 keyspec

```
byte[] key = Base64.encodeBase64(publicKey.getBytes());
x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
```

Comment: It looks like that text is already base 64 encoded.  You want to base 64 decode that string to get the bytes.

Comment: i tried to decode it instead and still got the error

Answer (score 0):

`encodeBase64` encodes into base 64. I think you want to decode the public key, not to encode it. Of course, if you decode manually you should first strip off the header and the footer. Finally, SSH uses it's own key format, so you should use a library that reads SSH public keys, not just the decoder used for `X509KeySpec`.

Comment: Thanks. Which library can i use to read ssh public keys that are sent to me as plain text? I have already tried decoding the public key as noted previously and it did not work. What does a X509keySpec key look like?